# toggle active/inactive states in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to update active and inactive status in laravel with toggle. Status show perfectly. But controller doesn't work. Here
is my code.

**blade file**

```
@foreach($data as $srial => $row)

      <tr>
        <td>{{$row->name}}</td>

        <td>

          <input data-id="{{$row->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $row->status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    
</td>
      </tr>
      
      @endforeach
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle-class').change(function () {
        let status = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
        let userId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('/changeStatus') }}',
            data: {'status': status, 'user_id': userId},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function changeUserStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $file=DB::table('students')->where('id',$id)->first();
        $user=$file->status;
        $task ['status']= $request->user_id;
 
    $data=DB::table('students')->where('id',$request)->update($task);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/changeStatus', 'AdminController@ChangeUserStatus')->name('/changeStatus');
```

Comment: $task ['status']= $request->user_id; is this supposed to be $request->status?

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow query:

```
public function changeUserStatus(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('students')->where('id', $request->user_id)->update(['status' => $request->status]);
}
```

Where condition is wrong, need to pass user id and status in update.

and in view, ajax type must be post

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle-class').change(function () {
        let status = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
        let userId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "{{ route('/changeStatus') }}",
            data: {'status': status, 'user_id': userId},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Route must be post type

```
Route::post('/changeStatus', 'AdminController@ChangeUserStatus')->name('/changeStatus');
```

Comment: does the value change in the database?

Comment: No, value doesn't change.

Comment: can you check the browser console for jquery error?

Comment: `Shift + CTRL + J` for console

Comment: There are 4 massege `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

Comment: instead  of `$(this).prop('checked')` use `$(this).is(':checked')` or `$(this).attr('checked')` this may help you.

Comment: and `$('.toggle-class').change(function () {` change it to `$('.toggle-class').on('change', function() {`

Comment: which jquery version you are using?

Comment: Now 3 massege `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

Comment: jquery version 3.4.1